# RegEx for special characters and decimals except for commas

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Regex testing for special characters, decimal except for hyphen, commas, alpha-numeric.

#### Attempt

```
^(\+|-)?([0-9]+)$/
```

I'm trying to write a regex to match special characters, decimal except for commas, a hyphen, alpha-numeric.

Comment: This website usually helps me building any regex: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Comment: /^(\+|-)?([0-9]+)$/ i have tried this but its accepting commas and characters and hyphens.

Comment: Please provide several examples of input that should match and input that should not match, with a brief explanation of each.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you might just want to list the chars that you wish in a `[]` and test it. Maybe, a simple expression like this would be desired for you and you could work on it:

```
^([?!"'~&%$*@#0-^@9]+)$
```

You might want to use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/0RWSFR/1) and design an expression that you wish, then test it with real samples and maybe change it as you wish.

[image]

You can also use an online visualizer to view how your expression would work:

[image]